# React-map-gl and deck.gl plot bounds

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I was just wondering what the plotting bounds are for react-map-gl and deck.gl is, im trying to plot coordinates e.g. [90,20] and it doesnt plot on the map. Im simply using an icon layer and a staticmap.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Latitude should, in reality, be max 90 and min -90. This is not the case it is more around -87 to 87, though this does plot an icon off map but it is visible, -85 to 85 is on map bounds.

Longitude is infinite, this spans the entire globe horizontally therefore is infinite.

**Edit

At the time of using react-map-gl and deck.gl I could plot longitudes of 300, therefore in theory due to coding this would make the longitude limits infinite. In reality we all know the real limits of lat are 90 - -90 and 180 -180.

Comment: What complete non-sense, longitude is obviously not infinite otherwie the earth could not be round... have you seen a globe?

Longitude has a range between  -180 to 180

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned within my answer that, at the time, I could plot longitudes of 300 with this still appearing on the map, therefore due to the code in theory you could plot any number you wanted alone the longitude, therefore in theory being infinite. There is also no need to be rude about this, this is a site for learning not having digs at developers seeking help.